# How to share libraries in multi applications using rebar?

Tags: erlang, rebar, reltool

I have a project structure like this:

```
ROOT/
    apps/
        common_lib_1/
            src/*.erl
            include/*.hrl
        common_lib_2/
            src/*.erl
            include/*.hrl
        common_lib_3/
            src/*.erl
            include/*.hrl
        login_server/
            src/*.erl
        game_server
            src/*.erl
    rel/
```

I want to distribute `game_server` and `login_server`, `game_server` depends on `common_lib_1` and `common_lib_2`, `login_server` depends on `common_lib_1` and `common_lib_3`.

If execute `rebar create-node nodeid=xxx` in `rel/game_server` and `rel/login_server`, when I create distribute using `rebar generate`, many duplicated files will generated.

I want to distribute thems with a clean structure like this:

```
my_game/
    bin/
        game_server_region_1 # startup script of game server with region 1
        game_server_region_2 # startup script of game server with region 2
        login_server         # startup script of login server
        ...                  # other common files
    erts-5.10.3/
        bin/
    lib/
        stdlib-1.19.3/
        sasl-2.3.3/
        common_lib_1-1.0.0/
        common_lib_2-1.0.0/
        common_lib_3-1.0.0/
        game_server-1.0.0/
        login_server-1.0.0/
        ...                  # other shared libraries
    releases/
        1.0.0/
            game_server.boot
            game_server.rel
            game_server.script
            login_server.boot
            login_server.rel
            login_server.script
            game_server_region_1_vm.args
            game_server_region_1_sys.config
            game_server_region_1_vm.args
            game_server_region_1_sys.config
            login_server_vm.args
            login_server_sys.config
        RELEASES
        start_erl.data
```

I expect all applications shared libraries, they have own startup script, vm and sys config.

How to write a clean reltool.config to do this?